# getElementsByTagName() method doesn't select the specific node in GWT

Tags: java, xml, gwt

I want to select specific node in `GWT` using `getElementsByTagName()` method. I wrote the following code

```
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.NodeList;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser;

Document comOrgRegDOM = XMLParser.parse(xml);
Element comOrgRegElement = comOrgRegDOM.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nodelist = comOrgRegElement.getElementsByTagName("comOrgReg/statutoryFund");
System.out.println("nodelist size:"+nodelist.getLength());
```

My `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <comOrgReg>
      <statutoryFund>
         <depositType>Money</depositType>
         <monetoryValue>1000000</monetoryValue>
         <nonMonetoryValue/>
         <totalValue>1000000</totalValue>
     </statutoryFund>
</comOrgReg>
```

But I get this output

```
nodelist size:0
```

My question is : can I use "comOrgReg/statutoryFund" as argument for `getElementsByTagName()` method, because `getElementsByTagName("statutoryFund")` works. And If I can't, how to get the specific "comOrgReg/statutoryFund" node.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question already answers the quesiton "can I use comOrgReg/statutoryFund". Since you are getting a size of 0 in NodeList, it means the answer is no. Do you mean to ask something else?

Comment: I just want to select the given node "comOrgReg/statutoryFund" using GWT. Yes, I tried getElementsByTagName() method, but no result. Maybe there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think paths are supported like that.

Try this:

```
Element statutoryFund = comOrgRegElement
    .getElementsByTagName("comOrgReg")
    .getItem(0)
    .getElementsByTagName("statutoryFund")
    .getITem(0);
```

Or use a loop if there's more than one.

Comment: Be careful with getItem() since that can return non-elements like TextNodes for the whitespace...